# Possible existence of entire function

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Is there an entire function $f$ such that $f(z)=1/z$ for all z in the plane punctured at $0$?

I am viewing it as a problem to analytically extend the function $1/z$ in the entire plane which is not allowed by Riemann's removable singularity theorem as $z=0$ is a pole here.

Am I thinking right? What am I missing? What are the ways to counter these type of questions?

Comment: Can such an $f$ be continuous at $0$? What is $\lim_{z \to 0} f(z)$?

Comment: Oh yes. The limit will not exist for such a function.

Comment: Is this the general approach? Isn't that a necessary condition that we just checked? If it fails, we need not look further. What if the limit existed? In that case, would it not be a removable singularity? And hence could be extended to an analytic function.